# MongoDB GridFS huge wt file

Tags: mongodb, database-backups, gridfs

I use MongoDB to store my costumers files.

The .wt collection data file, referred to my GridFS collection, has been coming greater each day - today it has > 60GiB and a my incremental backup always see this file as a different one.

Is there a way to split this wt file?

Answer (score 0):

WiredTiger configuration parameters are defined [here](https://github.com/wiredtiger/wiredtiger/blob/develop/src/config/config_def.c), you can try finding some that are related to file size.

You can pass them to `mongod` as `--wiredTigerEngineConfigString 'log=(prealloc=false,file_max=20MB),cache_size=64M'` or [via configuration file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage-options).